# {this.state.object} Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a response json like this:

```
{
    "variables": {
        "lock": 0,
        "pos": 55,
        "pos_on": 55,
        "pos_off": 150
    },
    "id": "11",
    "name": "Lock_table_2",
    "hardware": "esp8266",
    "connected": true
}
```

and I try to show the lock value in 'variables' object
so I write

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        dock_1: {},       // define a empty json
        dock_2: {},
        dock_3: {},
    }
}
pingIP() {
    axios
        .get('http://192.168.50.225:8888/test_check')
        .then(response => {
            let data = response.data.list;  // return value is a list
            this.setState({                 // every 2 sec setState
                dock_1: data[0],            // data[0] -> 192.168.50.40's json
                dock_2: data[1],
                dock_3: data[2],
            })
        })
}
render(){
    return (
        <p>{this.state.dock_1.variables.lock}</p>
    );
}
```

but I got this error
[in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJlJ0.png)

So I tried this

```
render(){
    return (
        <p>{this.state.dock_1.variables}</p>
    );
}
```

then here comes the another error message
[in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtuJX.png)

here is the get request return value

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "connected": true,
      "hardware": "esp8266",
      "id": "10",
      "name": "Lock_table_1",
      "variables": {
        "lock": 1,
        "pos": 80,
        "pos_off": 160,
        "pos_on": 80
      }
    },
    {
      "connected": true,
      "hardware": "esp8266",
      "id": "10",
      "name": "Lock_table_2",
      "variables": {
        "lock": 1,
        "pos": 80,
        "pos_off": 160,
        "pos_on": 80
      }
    },
    {
      "connected": true,
      "hardware": "esp8266",
      "id": "10",
      "name": "Lock_table_3",
      "variables": {
        "lock": 1,
        "pos": 80,
        "pos_off": 160,
        "pos_on": 80
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

the return value is a list
in order to get first value so I wrote data[0], data[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJlJ0.png) ...

what's happening in here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! *"I have a response json like this"* That structure isn't an array (or array-like list), but your code is clearly expecting an array or array-like list...?

Comment: Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Post code and markup and such **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247 Include the error messages, as text, in the question.

Comment: what is the value of your variable `data` after assigning it?

Comment: You can check my answer with a working sample.

Comment: I update the request value up there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your response is an array of 3 items like this:

```
[
  {
    variables: {
      lock: 0,
      pos: 55,
      pos_on: 55,
      pos_off: 150
    },
    id: "11",
    name: "Lock_table_2",
    hardware: "esp8266",
    connected: true
  },
  {
    variables: {
      lock: 1,
      pos: 44,
      pos_on: 56,
      pos_off: 151
    },
    id: "11",
    name: "Lock_table_3",
    hardware: "esp8267",
    connected: false
  },
  {
    variables: {
      lock: 2,
      pos: 45,
      pos_on: 57,
      pos_off: 152
    },
    id: "11",
    name: "Lock_table_4",
    hardware: "esp8268",
    connected: true
  }
]
```

So you can access the dock 1 variable lock using Inline If with Logical && Operator to prevent null exception.

```
   <p>{this.state.dock_1.variables && this.state.dock_1.variables.lock}</p>
```

A sample working codesandbox with a fake api:

https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-chaplygin-r1yxd

Comment: Oh wow it works just like this
thank you very mush
but what is the '&&' meaning?
why should I put that in here?

Comment: @mushding  && is described here: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator